# Permanently prevent an update from being installed on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update, updates

Is there a way to permanently bar the following update from being installed whenever I install updates?

> Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2975719)

I have my settings on "Download updated but let me choose whether to install them". Windows seems to honour this, but when I choose to install the other updates, the same problem still occurs. Whenever I restart the system to complete the installation of the updates, it ends up with the error:

> We couldn't complete the updates, Undoing changes. Don't turn off your computer

However it appears that all of the updates installed fine except for this one. I have narrowed it down to this particular update as it has stuck around for quite a few iterations of updates while the others install fine.

I manually perform the updates and I uncheck this update every time but the same error occurs after it finishes "working on updates" after the restart. It takes a good 15-20 minutes for Windows to "undo changes" despite the checked updates completing fine.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: you should better fix the real issue. Share the folder **C:\Windows\logs\CBS** so that I can see **WHY** the update fails to install.

Comment: Is there anything specific you're looking for? The file is over 200 MB

Comment: You used to be able to set updates to hidden on [Windows Update](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/) on earlier Widows releases. I presume it is still true.

Comment: don't look for anything. Copy the complete folder to the desktop, zip the folder and upload the zip (OneDrive, Dropbox) and post a link here.